# jquery Custom Slide Header Menu

Tags: jquery, menu, slide

What i want to do is as follows:

I have a header bar at the top of my page. It looks like this:

Title: Admin [Customers] [Reports]

The html for this is:

```
<div id="header">
<span class="title">Title:</span>
<div id="section" class="active"><a href="javascript:void();">Admin</a></div>
<div id="section" class="hidden"><a href="javascript:void();">Customers</a></div> 
<div id="section" class="hidden"><a href="javascript:void();">Reports</a></div>
</div>
```

All styled nicely with CSS, okay.  So obviously, the active one can be seen and the hidden cannot be seen.  I want to click on the active one, then fadeIn and display the hidden ones, which I have managed to so far, and then, when you select the either of the hidden ones the other two fade out, and the selected one slides into place of the active one.

But I use the animate property and it all goes askew.  It animates for some reason to off the page, not so much that I cant see it, but enough, and outside of my DIVs aswell.  I tried putting an absolute DIV around it, as I thought that then when I minus the

```
animate({left: $(this).offset().left)});
```

Left, it would animate ONLY inside the DIV.

The CSS for the header, title and section is:

```
#header     { position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 1000px;
        height: 60px; text-align: left; display: block; }       
.title, #section, #section a
        {position: relative; left: 10px; font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
        font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold;  float: left;}
.title  {color: #9900ff; display: inline-block; width: 150px;}
#section, #section a    
    {color: #CC81FD; font-size: 50px; margin-right: 5px; }
#section.active, #section.active a
          {display: inline-block; text-decoration: none;}
#section.hidden a {display: none; text-decoration: none;}
#section a:hover  {color: #9900FF;}
```

and my current (but failing) jQuery is:

```
var curX = $(this).offset().left;
var curElement = this;
$(this).animate({left: -curX});
$("#section a").not(curElement).fadeOut("slow");
```

If anyone can help that would be amazing!

Comment: Ok, now just a question... after the you click the *now visible 'hidden' one* - you plan to hide all other links, right? but than... how you plan to go back to the initial state?

Comment: Umm i'm really not sure, to be honest I didnt think that far ahead :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after 1 hour work i think I've done it!
I hope it will work like you meant!
But I changed the (invalid) ID "section" to a class!
Here you can see it:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kE5u9/4/)

Comment: wow, that is amazing, I am extremely impressed.  It is interesting the way it works after you change the selection, you keep their original positions which I wouldnt have thought of doing.

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this and spending an hour on it was very very kind of you.  Thank you so much, I will definitely use this.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove the firstclick variable! It is unimportant, was just an other attempt ;-)

Comment: Good code too, I dont know why you've used a function instead of simply $('.section > a').click? and I am not familiar with the greater than in the CSS ident.

Comment: Also I cant figure out here how you managed to animate them, you only ever seem to animate the opacity? Do you mind explaining it a bit for me, if thats okay?

Comment: First I animate (by fading out) the opacity!
Then I'm using `.hide(500)` (for the already invisible elements) to disable the links and let the visible one slide to the left! And when it fades in, i first check if it's the left (first) div. If so, then I don't let it slide in! If not I use `.show(500)` let the div slide to the old position, then then fading in the hidden ones!
That might be helpful:
[jQuery - hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
[jQuery - show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)